# How to get the compatibility level of a database from analysis server?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-sql-database, ssas

I searched around and found there is a way to get compatibility level of a database in powershell through something like:

```
    Import-Module SqlServer

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$DB;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection($sqlConnection)
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($conn) 

$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database  
$db = $srv.Databases.Item("$DB")  

$comp_lvl = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.CompatibilityLevel  
$comp_lvl = $db.CompatiblityLevel  
Write-Host "Compatibility level =" $db.CompatibilityLevel
```

However, I am getting errors trying to get compatibility level of a database that is on an analysis server

> Exception getting "Item": "Failed to connect to server ..."

I realized it is probably working for a regular database engine, but something else may be used for an analysis server. I looked around on MS Docs and didnt really find anything helpful.

SO is this even possible?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to find something on this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/hh213141(v=sql.100)

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$as = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
$as.connect("$Server")  

$as.databases

Write-Host "Compatibility level ="$as.DefaultCompatibilityLevel
```

but this returns ALL databases back...

I want to specify just one database to get the compatibility level of...

I tried this,

```
$as.databases["$Database"]
```

but it seems not to return the proper level, because the DB i am passing has a lvl of 1103, not 1200...

Comment: Are you running Azure Analysis Services or are you running SQL Analysis Server? Analysis Services PowerShell Reference = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/powershell/analysis-services-powershell-reference?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT check my UPDATE in the post plz :), also the DB says this so im not sure: Azure Analysis Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$as = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
$as.connect("$Server")  

$c = $as.Databases | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq $Database }

Write-Host "Compatibility level =" $c.CompatibilityLevel
```